# java consume SOAP service with authorization header

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am trying to insert authentication information into a header request that is going to 
an older SOAP based .Net based service (.asmx).  I've used ws-input under NetBeans 8.1
to import the wsdl and generate the calls to the client, but unable to see how to insert
header information.  I have tried the following approach to insert the header information,
but the web service is returning an error indicating it doesn't see the authentication.
Any ideas?

```
try
{
    com.CompanyService.api.CompanyServiceApi service = new com.CompanyService.api.CompanyServiceApi();
    com.CompanyService.api.CompanyServiceApiSoap port = service.getCompanyServiceApiSoap();

    Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
    req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://api.CompanyService.com/CompanyServiceApi.asmx");

    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    headers.put("LoginName", Collections.singletonList("WebService"));
    headers.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("xxxxxxx"));
    req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);

    res = port.getCustomers(getCustomersRequest);
}
catch (Exception e) { 
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Comment: Hard to know without looking the specs... but isnt it a basic HTTP authentication? Like in Key = "Authorization" and value = "Basic " + Base64Encode(user + ":" + password). Dont think I have another sugestion though. Sorry :/.

Comment: Yes, I have tried [code] headers.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Basic V2ViU2VydmljZTpmenU4dHckX1E4SDI="));  [/code] and have not gotten good results either.

Comment: Usually SOAP authentication data is sent into SOAP headers. But if you try  to use Authorization header, remove `Arrays.asList("`. Just the value